# Creating log files in sequence

Tags: logging, file-io, asp-classic

I am writing a function in classic ASP where I need to store log files based on HTTP requests and responses. if I don't handle those logs correctly then they will grow up considerably in size. I would like to ask you what is the best practice (if there is any) and how can I deal with it.

I have thought of creating a new log file every time the current file reaches a specified size, but I am not sure whether this is an efficient solution. Any ideas or examples will be greatly appreciated. This is my function that currently logs:

```
Function WriteLog(ByVal psMessage) 
    Dim oFs: Set oFs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Application.Lock
        Dim oTs: Set oTs = oFs.OpenTextFile(logFile, 8, True)    '8 = ForAppending 
        oTs.WriteLine Now() & vbTab & psMessage 
        oTs.Close 
    Application.UnLock
    Set oTs = Nothing 
    Set oFs = Nothing 
    WriteLog = True 
End Function
```

Comment: How about just having a new log file each day (make the date part of the log file name).

Comment: You are likely going to run into concurrency issues if you try to scale this approach.  When you open a file with ForAppending, it locks both read and writes to file except for the process that has an exclusive lock.  This means if you get 1000 visitors at the same instant the file is being written to, they will get an error.

Comment: If you need to handle lots of concurrent connections, you may want to look into a lightweight file database such as [SQLite](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/).